# Tumblr Theme looks different on different screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, screen-resolution

So I created a Tumblr Theme for my new roleplay group there. It looks GREAT for me! But a lot of people have been saying that it looks very disorganized with floating boxes in random spaces. I was obviously quite confused so I asked for some screenshots. We figured out that the problem is different screen resolutions. Is there a way to fix this and have my theme look the same on every resolution using HTML (or CSS or JS)?

This is what *I* see.

[image]

This is what some other people see

[image]

Comment: This question is way to broad for a helpful answer. Your Page seems to have relative width's, which will result in different looks on different screens (have you tried mobile yet?). Take a look at responsive Design, and if you have trouble with an specific Problem, show us some code, and we are here to help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i can think of without seeing the code is the format which is used on Height and Width.

You are using either pixels or % right? Well if so add this in:
(It's required for this to work)

```
<style>
html,body{min-width: 100vw; max-width: 100vw; min-height: 100vh; max-height: 100vh;}
```

When this is done, change all width and height and font-size to 1-100vw and 1-100vh (1=1% of the viewport)
Also if you haven't done already, you should give all divs/buttons etc. an absolute position.

Add ths to every div etc. CSS:

```
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
Transform: translate(1-100vw,1-100vh);
```

This will make the upper left cornor to be the anchor for the divs. With the Transform: translate you can move it around as you like. If you do it like this, you will be sure that i will always look the same on any display :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! :D I'll be putting all that in tomorrow and I'll let you know how it goes!! :D

Comment: So you said to switch the top, left, and font-size, how about do I, like, convert fontsize from px to vw or vh? Roughly speaking.

Comment: Here is an example of some of my CSS:
    `.Div_log
{height: 4vh; 
    width: 15vw;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1vw; 
     transform: translate(15vw, 7.8vh);}`

I just read the answer again, and yeah sorry it was a bit hard to understand without an example xD

Comment: Remember to choose this as the Answer so others can find it and use it ^^